# How to make these string matching functions in Haskell?

Tags: string, haskell

Consider the following multi-line string `S`:

```
apple
banana berry
cantelope
```

I'm trying to write/locate Haskell functions which I will call in this post `or-match` and `and-match`. Here are some examples of what they should do:

```
or-match S ("apple","berry")

{- should return the two line string:
apple
banana berry
-}

and-match S ("apple", "berry") --should return the empty string, or something like "No matches."

and-match S ("banana" "berry") --should return a single line containing "banana berry"
```

In the above examples, I used the type `(String, String)` for the domain argument of `or-match` and `and-match`. I'm not sure that's the best way to go about it though, since I might want to use more than two arguments. I'm new to Haskell though, and am not sure how to make an tuple of arbitrary length the argument of a function.

**In sum, the overall question of this post:** How do I make `or-match` and `and-match` in Haskell, such that the domain argument for each of these functions is a tuple of arbitrary length (or some type that allows an arbitrary length of searches)?

Answer (score 4):

You may write

```
andMatchPred, orMatchPred :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
andMatchPred needles haystack = all (`elem` haystack) needles
orMatchPred  needles haystack = any (`elem` haystack) needles
```

Then your desired functions might be written as

```
andMatch, orMatch :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
andMatch = filter . andMatchPred
orMatch  = filter . orMatchPred
```

There should be plenty of opportunities to improve the efficiency later if that turns out to be a bottleneck, but the simple and readable implementation should come first.

A quick use in ghci to show how it might be used:

```
> let s = [["apple"],["banana","berry"],["cantelope"]]
> andMatch ["apple", "berry"] s
[]
> orMatch ["apple", "berry"] s
[["apple"],["banana","berry"]]
```

Answer (score 2):

> such that the domain argument for each of these functions is a tuple of arbitrary length (or some type that allows an arbitrary length of searches)?

You're looking for a list, specifically in this case `[String]`.  Tuples are fixed length but allow for a different type in each position, lists are homogeneous meaning each value has to have the same type, but are of arbitrary length.

So what you're looking for is are functions of type

```
orMatch, andMatch :: [String] -> [String] -> [String]
```

You'll need a function `hasSubString :: String -> String -> Bool` that you'll have to write yourself, but your code could look something like the following pseudo-code:

```
orMatch lines searchTerms = filter (\line -> any (hasSubString line) searchTerms) lines
andMatch lines searchTerms = filter (\line -> all (hasSubString line) searchTerms) lines
```

Where

```
hasSubString string substring
```

returns `True` if `substring` appears in `string`, and `False` otherwise.  For example `hasSubString "hello, world" "world" == True`, `hasSubString "hello, world" "unicorns" == False`

Comment: It's not necessary to implement `hasSubString` yourself; the standard libraries have it as `isInfixOf`, and more efficient versions exist on Hackage.